# If statement within if statement is not running

Tags: java, if-statement

So i am trying to make a text based rpg game and what is supposed to happen here is when you activate a hunt by typing hunt it asks you yes or no. However even when i input yes, the you killed the boar message does not pop up. I am fairly new to java so sorry if the code is bad.

```
//Branches
            if (ins.equals("branches") && loc.equals("forest")) {
                System.out.println("You got a branch");
                ib++;
            } else if (ins.equals("branches") && !"forest".equals(loc)) {
                System.out.println("You need to be in the forest to cut branches");
            } else if (ins.equals("bcount")) {
                System.out.println(ib);
            }
            //Branches


            //Stones
            if (ins.equals("stones") && loc.equals("mountains")) {
                System.out.println("You got a stone");
                is++;
            } else if (ins.equals("stones") && !"mountains".equals(loc)) {
                System.out.println("You need to be in the mountains to gather stones");
            } else if (ins.equals("scount")) {
                System.out.println(is);
            }
            //Stones


            //Spears
            if (ins.equals("spear") && is >= 1 && ib >= 1) {
                System.out.println("+1 spear");
                is--;
                ib--;
                ispear++;
            } else if (ins.equals("spear") && is < 1) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient resources");
            } else if (ins.equals("spear") && ib < 1) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient resources");
            } else if (ins.equals("spearcount")) {
                System.out.println(ispear);
            }
            //Spears


            //Hunt
            if (ins.equals("hunt") && ispear >= 1) {

                System.out.println("A wild boar comes charging at you! Throw spear? (yes or no)");
                


                if (ins.equals("yes")) {

                    System.out.println("You killed the boar!");

                }


            } else if (ins.equals("hunt") && ispear < 1) {

                System.out.println("You dont have any spears");

            }

        }
```

Comment: I think it's because you aren't reading the user input after the first `if` check. In the parent expression you checked whether `ins` was `hunt`, and inside it you check whether it is `yes`. `ins` was never changed, so it will never satisfy `ins.equals("yes")`

Comment: From the look of it you can enter the part of code that says "You killed the Board" by having ins == "hunt" but then ins will never equal "yes" since you never updated the value of ins and it was established that ins == "hunt".

Comment: Your logic is illogical! if ins.equals("hunt") and ispear >=1 then ins cannot equal "yes" and ispear cannot be < 1

Comment: @alexM Please post all other if statements if you can

Comment: @ShaanK here are the rest

Comment: @alexM How do you read user input? If you use a scanner, just use `ins = yourScannerObject.nextLine()` after you printed `"A wild boar comes..."` and it should work fine.

Comment: User input is being read by something at the top of the while loop. I just had to make another one inside the if statement for hunt and this was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If the while loop at the top controls the input then it is not possible for the code to get back to that inner if statements because `ins` cannot equal both "hunt" and "yes" at the same time. You need to do what @Spectric suggested in the comments and read the input again, or you need to use another way.

In the example below, we have used a boolean as a flag `Boolean hunting = false;`, and an OR condition `||` to allow us to get back inside the hunting section `if (huting == true || ins.equals("hunt")....)` then finally we need to make sure we trigger the flag on/off when hunting starts/ends like this `hunting = true;` or `hunting = false;`

Then all put together:

```
//Flag that allows us to trigger hunting
//This needs to be placed outside of the while loop
Boolean hunting = false;

//While loop that gets input and prints the next instruction
while (ins != null)
{
    //Your code here to get the input
    //...
    //ins = scanner.nextLine();
    //...
    
    //Hunt
    //add an or "||" condition so that if the hunting flag is true then we can get back inside this if statement:
    if (hunting == true || ins.equals("hunt") && ispear >= 1)
    {
        //Set the hunting flag to true, so that we can get back to here in the next loop:
        hunting = true;
        System.out.println("A wild boar comes charging at you! Throw spear? (yes or no)");
        if (ins.equals("yes"))
        {
            System.out.println("You killed the boar!");

            //Reset the hunting flag so future commands don't break:
            hunting = false;
        }
        //Make sure you have an else statement to set the hunting flag back to false
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The boar ran away!");

            //Reset the hunting flag so future commands don't break:
            hunting = false;
        }
    }
    else if (ins.equals("hunt") && ispear < 1)
    {
        System.out.println("You dont have any spears");
    }
}
```